# OpenCV - Too many circles detected

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

#### Aim

Detect moon craters and draw circles on them using OpenCV and Tkinter
(This is for a school science competition - ideally, later craters will be highlighted red and areas between them that are above a certain size will be highlighted)

#### Problem

Too many circles are detected

#### The Need

Could someone please suggest what steps may be being missed, as plainly as possible.  Or provide comment on actionable steps to take from here.

#### Additional challenge

This project is being undertaken by my 10yo son. He's working hard on this but I am not able to properly support this - it's outside of my expertise.

(I have asked on this previously on his behalf, but didn't have enough information and it has changed somewhat since. I have had him rewrite this query a number of times so he learns that the better information he provides, the better help he can receive. So please bear in mind, as simply as answers can be given, the better.)

#### More Detail

Using OpenCV in Tkinter, too many circles are detected.  Despite looking through many articles, and tutorials, it has not been solved.  I'm wondering if this is missing a step such as thresholding, or something similar.  I'll be passing the replies to him, and helping through them if need be, as well.

Thanks in advance!

#### Images

[image: Original Image]
Original Image

[image]
Processed

#### Notes

##### The aim: (In gui):

1. loads an image
2. finds the circles in the image

##### What I am doing(In the code)

1.Defines "Open"
2. In "Open" find image/file then load it up
3. Defines "Find Craters"
4. In find craters finds a circle with 'Min radius = 20 Max radius = 200'
5. Turns all the functions in to buttons

##### What I am trying to do

1. Blur the Image
2. Identify circles

#### Code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np
import cv2


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("AAMLS")
root.geometry("1100x600")


def open():
    global my_image
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="images", title="Select A File", filetypes=(("jpg files", "*.jpg"),("all files", "*.*")))
    my_label.config(text=filename)
    my_image = Image.open(filename)
    tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(my_image)
    my_image_label.config(image=tkimg)
    my_image_label.image = tkimg  # save a reference of the image


def find_craters():
    global image
    global my_image_label
    # convert PIL image to OpenCV image
    circles_image = np.array(my_image.convert('RGB'))
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(circles_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_img,(5,5),0)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20,
                              param1=20, param2=60, minRadius=20, maxRadius=200)
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

        for i in circles[0]:
            # draw the outer circle
            cv2.circle(circles_image, (i[0],i[1]), i[2], (0,255,0), 2)
            # draw the center of the circle
            cv2.circle(circles_image, (i[0],i[1]), 2, (0,0,255), 3)
            #circles_img = cv2.Laplacian(circles_image,cv2.CV_64F)

        # convert OpenCV image back to PIL image
    image = Image.fromarray(circles_image)
        # update shown image
    my_image_label.image.paste(image)


btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Load Terrain", command=open).pack()
btn2 = tk.Button(root, text="Find Craters", command=find_craters).pack()


# for the filename of selected image
my_label = tk.Label(root)
my_label.pack()

# for showing the selected image
my_image_label = tk.Label(root)
my_image_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the number of circles, there are essentially these parameters in HoughCircles:

- min_dist: increase this value to find circles with a larger distance
- maxRadius: reduce this parameter to avoid circles that contain more than one crater
- param1: higher values make the edge detector less sensitive; only clear cut edges will be used (set param2 always to 3*param1)

You'll need to play around with these parameters to find a good setting. As a next step, I would do:

```py
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 30,
                              param1=40, param2=120, minRadius=20, maxRadius=80)
```

If then the circles are too few, relax the conditions to get more circles.

Comment: Thanks.  It has provided much better results, though still needs some work.  I'll upload the results later.  He is also adding thresholding to increase effectiveness.